# iOS7 UIWebView scroll indicator disappearing

Tags: ios7, uiwebview

I've noticed weird behaviour in my UIWebView using iOS 7.0 SDK. This behaviour wasn't there in iOS 6, and my code regarding this webview hasn't changed.

I have a storyboard, not using autolayout, autoresize mask for the webview is *everything* selected.

I have scale pages to fit set to YES.

When I load a local html file, it displays fine and upon scrolling, the webview will show the scroll indicator.
When I rotate the device, the webview resizes fine, it's rect is correct size, the page displays as expected, however the scroll indicator is not visible

Here's the kicker. If I don't scroll before I rotate, the scroll indicator is visible when I start scrolling AFTER the rotate.
If I DO scroll before the rotate, the scroll indicator is not visible after the rotate.

I checked the html, there is no jquery or js that will change the overflow in regards to orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found the solution, I was using a subclassed UIWebView and overriding the layoutSubviews to not draw the gradient shadows above and below the scrollview (as it has by default).

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // hide the shadows at the top and bottom of the webview's frame
    for (UIView* shadowView in [self.scrollView subviews])
    {
        if ([shadowView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [shadowView setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Well guess what was a UIImageView? The Scroll Indicator! I removed this code and the problem went away